# How often to refetch data from server?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment and the data displayed are fetched from a network call.
I am using `onSaveInstanceState` in order to avoid fetching the data again when the orientation changes, but if I understand the lifecycle for fragments correctly as long as the app is never destroyed (either explicit by the user or because the Android OS kills the activity due to lack of resources) the data from the server will never be refreshed.
If I have understood this part correctly, I would need to define some way to periodically refetch the data from the server or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There are no rules about data refresh. It depends on your app, your data, etc. If you fetch a list of receipts, you do not need to implement a refresh mechanism. But if you fetch, I don't know, the exchange rate of currencies, you must have one.

What about a **pull to refresh** pattern ?

Comment: But I am right that the data will only be refreshed on app restart the way I describe?

Comment: It depends on where you make your network call : in onResume(), the call will be made every time the fragment/activity is shown ; in onCreate(), every time it's created

Comment: But if I do it `onResume` then won't it fire on every orientation change?

Comment: yes, it would be fired. Use instead `onCreate()` with `savedInstanceState`

Comment: But then won't I have the same issue? Update only on every application restart?

Comment: Every time your fragment/activity is created.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: One app can contains one or more Activity. One Activity can contains one or more Fragment. When you first display an ActivityA, the `onCreate()` method is called. If you start another ActivityB and then go back to ActivityA, `onCreate()` will not be called but `onResume()`. That's for the "return back" case. For the App restart, your data will be fetched only if the corresponding Activity is created. That's why I distinguish the "App restart" from the "Activity creation"

Comment: So basically `onCreate()` I request the data from the server and on `onResume` I use the cached data? In this case then `onSaveInstance` is not relevant since the saved bundle is only available to `onCreate`

Comment: Have I got that right? Then when ever the activity is recreated it will fetch the data? Which would happen if: 1) User goes back from activity 2) Activity is killed in background right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Android Architecture components ViewModel and LiveData to save the data during screen rotations preventing multiple calls to the server for screen rotation changes. This is the preferred method Google seem to be pushing to their developers https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

To prevent the data from going stale I would either let the user decide when to update using the "Pull to Update" (as described in the other answer) or add a timer to update if the fragment has been in the foreground for an extended period of time using the method described here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks

Comment: Do you have some example code for the `add a timer to update if the fragment has been in the foreground....`?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example for periodic updates.